# Serious CSS situation. Totally stumped

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

I've been working websites for 15 years. PHP/mySQL for about 8. I'm not even sure what to say about this one.

Site being developed at http://173.201.224.43/Jason_Borjeson/jeba2012/site/index.php
css is at http://173.201.224.43/Jason_Borjeson/jeba2012/site/css/site.css

it is database driven with only one page, all url's are redirected through htaccess - just like wordpress. One html template and one css file.
Just went over the code - html5 and css3 compliant.
I compared generated source for the main page and one of the others and the only thing that changes is the content of 2 meta tags and the actual text of the page.

the main page (at url above) works great. but the links, which do pull up the correct test data, gets screwed up. I've checked in IE, FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera on OSX and Win - the result is the same in all of them.

Flushed cache on windows (which I am working on). Logged in to the Mac so no flush was needed.

I love css but it is not my strong suit. So, the main page is looking how it should. I am thinking I have my page structure wrong?

Comment: What is it you'd like the page to look like? Like the homepage? Or have the eagle somewhere else? At the top? What is wrong with the page specifically (I see it's not the same, but try to be specific)

Comment: Please define the actual problem. What "gets screwed up" in what way?

Comment: If the menu is supposed to be at the top, why is it at the bottom in the markup?

Comment: the main page - the first url in op - is how all the pages should look. The other pages - the eagle, the envelopes and the menu bar shift up and they should not. forgot to mention that in FF the text of the menu bar is at the bottom of the page when it should be in the black bar.

Comment: I like how it works, now.  You should just leave it that way.

Comment: like I said css is not my strong suit. when I put it logically where I want it in the html I cannot get everything to line line up as I want (i.e. the first page). Also, I wind up with a lot of extra space below the bottom of the content area.

Comment: thanks tim, but my girlfriend (who designed the page doesn't want it that way - personally I like the shift as well - with some refinement.

Comment: Christopher, My question is what am I missing/not doing/doing wrong that is causing this to happen.

Comment: I see your problem. (php). jk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the differing height of the `col-mid` element. You have more text in it on the home page.

This causes your `div#page` to have a different height, and when its height is too small, everything flies to the top of the page (when the `id="page"` element can fit above the others it does so).

You need to set some `min-height`s on elements or otherwise rein in your CSS. No poltergeists here.

Hint: use Chromium's "inspect element" function, it's a lifesaver to figure out what's up with CSS. It even lets you add and modify properties on the fly to see what the site would look like "if I did X".

Comment: borealid - thanks - DOH! - where/what is Chromium? I have a set of apps that I use and rarely venture beyond.

Comment: @cjtech: sorry, Google Chrome is probably a better fit [ https://www.google.com/chrome ]. Chromium is the debranded version. Use it to browse to the page, and you can right-click anything and hit "inspect element". Add and examine stuff on the right - "metrics" is a handy summary of element sizing/padding/margins.